# Creating an Image model

Tags: java, python, image, image-recognition

I am developing Image recognition software that will detect letters. I was wondering how I could create a model of a letter ("J" for example) so that when I take a picture with the letter "J" on it, the software will compare the image to the model and detect the letter "J".
How would I create the model?

Comment: Are you really sure you want to develop this yourself?  There are probably some open source libraries that can do this for you.

Comment: @aglassman I am starting this myself and then I have 4 or 5 people who are coming in to work on this with me. They are just behind on another project.

Comment: The way you create the model depends entirely on how you plan to do your recognition. So, you'll have to explain that before we can answer your question. And if you have no idea what class of algorithm you plan to use, you need to decide that first before there even _is_ an answer to your question.

Answer (score 2):

It seems you want to do OCR (Optical Character Recognition).

If this is only part of a larger project, try OpenCV. Even if you are making a commercial product, it has a permissive BSD license.

If you have set out to make a library of your own, read some of the papers available through any good search engine. There are many tutorials for machine learning and neural nets, which could produce the image models you want.

Comment: We are planning for it to be a commercial project. So I will look for some tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

You can use OpenCv library for java , this library contain Template Matching Model already implemented 
but the better thing for image recognition is using learning machine or neural network

Answer (score 0):

If I were going to do this, I would use normalized floats.

The letter A would be:
[(0.0,0.0),(0.5,1.0),(1.0,0.0),(0.1,0.5)(0.9,0.5)]

Update (further explanation)

So my thought is that you should be able to uniquely identify a letter with an array of normalized points.   Points would be at important features of the letter such as start, end, and midpoints of a line.  Curves would be sliced up into multiple smaller line segments, which would also be represented by points.

To use this model, the source image would be analyzed.  You would then analyze the image for text.  You could use edge detection and other methods to find text.  You'd also have to analyze for any transforms on the text.  After you figure out the transform of the text, you would split the text into characters, then analyze the character for the points of important features.  Then you would write an algorithm to normalize the points, and determine which model represents the found points most accurately.

Comment: @aglassman Could you expand on that and explain what you mean by that?